# How to correctly use select.select() with someSocket.recv

Tags: python, sockets, recv

This is printing "Received":

```
connection, clientAddr = mysocket.accept()
data = connection.recv(256)
print("Received")
```

This is printing "Timed out":

```
connection, clientAddr = mysocket.accept()
mysocket.setblocking(0)

readable, writeable, exceptional = select.select([mysocket], [], [], 5)
if mysocket in readable:
  data = connection.recv(256)
  print("Received")
else:
  print("Timed out")
```

The problem isn't that the 5 seconds is too short, the data is being received in the first code block within 5 seconds.
I tried removing the line, `mysocket.setblocking(0)`, no change.
I tried changing `if mysocket in readable:` to `if readable:` and also did `print(readable)`, still timed out and printing outputted, "[]".

Edit: **I also tried using `mysocket.recv(256)` in the `else` block, it received the data.**

I'm running this on a Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readable, writeable, exceptional = select.select([mysocket], [], [], 5)
if mysocket in readable:
  data = connection.recv(256)
```

You do a `select` in `mysocket` (the listener socket) and if `select` signals available data you do a read on `connection` (the connection socket). You should do a `select` on `connection` if you want to know if you can read from it instead. The select on `mysocket` should instead be done if you want to know if you can call `accept` to get another client connection.